# Swift property observer - example of didset vs willset uses

Tags: swift, properties, observer-pattern

I'm familiar with the meaning of property observer and how to use it.
However, what i really don't understand is when to use each of them.
It seems to me that it's not matter..
If i use didset i can use oldValue or the new value by using the property itself.. and if i'm using willset i can use newValue or the old value by using the property itself.
So.. oldValue in didset it's like property itself in willset, and newValue in willSet it's like property itself in didset:

```
var propObserve = 1 {
    willSet {
       print("my previous value was \(propObserve) and my future value will be \(newValue)")
    }

    didSet {
       print("my previous value was \(oldValue) and my future value will be \(propObserve)")
    }
}

propObserve = 2
```

I will get the same print from each of them.
I understand that willSet execute before, and didSet execute after the property set with the new value but still, i can use new and old values in both cases (in willSet and also in didSet)

Q1: When to prefer using one over the other?
Q2: Can u give me a concrete example of that use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There are many use cases for each, but here are a couple examples.

Use `willSet` to perform a validation on the new value, restrict it to a certain numerical range, round it off, or save it to a history of previous values. Using `willSet` give the programmer the ability to change the value before assignment.

Use `didSet` to perform any action after the value changes such as updating the user interface, reloading a table view, logging something to an API, or changing another related value. Using `didSet` assigns the value and allows actions to be taken based on that assignment.

In some other use cases, either would suffice.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but still, all the cases u r mentioned can be done with the other observe method of the property. save to history can be done with didSet and perform action as updating UI, reloading table view, loggin API can be done in willSet. if so, your comment didn't give a really answer to my question.

Comment: Have you found the answer you've been looking for? @r.pul